# React Native Card Layout - Struggling to Position Child Elements with Flexbox

Tags: android, css, react-native

I'm having some difficulty getting a particular layout to work in React Native. I'm using a Card from react-native-elements, and I'm trying to position an icon row at the bottom of each card, with an avatar row at the top and an image/description in the middle. I've been using flex: 1 and justifyContent: 'space-between' in an attempt to distribute space evenly between the elements, but I'm running into some issues.

Here's my code:

```
const RecentlyAdded = () => {
  const renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <Card containerStyle={styles.card}>
      <View style={styles.topContainer}>
        <View style={styles.avatarRow}>
          <Avatar source={{uri: item.avatar}} rounded size="small" />
          <View style={styles.userinfo}>
            <Text style={styles.username}>{item.username}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.timeAgo}>
              {moment(item.timeAdded).fromNow()}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
      </View>

      <Image source={{uri: item.image}} style={styles.image} />

      <View style={styles.middleContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.description} numberOfLines={2}>
          {item.description}
        </Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.iconRow}>
        <Ionicons name="chatbubble-outline" size={20} />
        <Text>{item.comments}</Text>
        <Ionicons name="heart-outline" size={20} />
        <Text>{item.favorites}</Text>
        <Text>Il ya deux heures</Text>
      </View>
    </Card>
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.mainTitle}>Récemment ajouté</Text>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

And the styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 22,
  },
  card: {
    backgroundColor: '#F7F7F8',
    borderColor: '#F7F7F8',
    flex: 1,
    borderRadius: 13,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    elevation: 0,
    padding: 10, 
    width: 250,
  },
  topContainer: {
   
  },
  middleContainer: {
  },
  mainTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  timeAgo: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: '#888',
  },
  image: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 150,
  },
  description: {
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  iconRow: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  avatarRow: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  username: {
    marginLeft: 10,
  },
});
```

I expect the iconRow to be positioned at the bottom of the card, with the image and description taking up any remaining space in between the avatarRow and iconRow. However, when I apply flex: 1 to the middleContainer, which contains the image and description, some views get hidden and the layout doesn't work as expected.

I've tried adding a maxHeight to the middleContainer, but this hasn't resolved the issue. I'm not sure why the total content height of topContainer + middleContainer + iconRow seems to exceed the Card's height, causing some content to be hidden.

I would really appreciate any suggestions on how I can fix this layout issue. Thanks in advance for your help!